# Trouble installing sip on osx for python3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install sip so I can install PyQt5. When I try to install with pip it gives the following error.

```
>>>pip3 install sip
Collecting sip
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sip
```

Does anyone know how I can get pip to find the sip package? I've also tried installing with brew but I need to install version 4.19 and brew installs 4.18.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can find downloads for SIP from the Python Package Index that pip normally downloads from, [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SIP). This will download a wheel file, which can be installed via the `wheel` python module.

`pip3 install wheel`, then do `python3 -m wheel install <path-to-downloaded-wheel>`.